# In moderncv \address, \email, \mobile are not working

Tags: texmaker, moderncv

This is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{casual}                       
\moderncvcolor{blue}                         
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.6cm} 

\settowidth{\footerboxwidth}{\usebox{\footerbox}}%

\firstname{Stefania}
\familyname{Dakourou}
\title{Rs Fellow}
\address{Navarinou 31}{15124 Marousi,Athens}
\mobile{+30 698 4385057}    
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Errors: There is no error but an alert appears as "File not found". But when I take all away from address then the pdf shows up in the TexMaker. I posted this question earlier and got no where. Someone suggested to reinstall entire MikTex and I did that too. Its still not working.

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document c
lass
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
fancyhdr.sty    
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
   xargs.sty    2008/03/22 v1.1  extended macro definitions  (mpg)
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
microtype.sty    2010/01/10 v2.4 Micro-typography with pdfTeX (RS)
microtype.cfg    2010/01/10 v2.4 microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er compatibility patches
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5 Variant command support
tweaklist.sty    
moderncvstylecasual.sty    2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter
 style scheme: casual
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r style scheme: classic
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolorblue.sty    2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter c
olor scheme: blue
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
inputenx.sty    2011/05/27 v1.10 Enhanced input encoding handling (HO)
ix-alias.def    2011/05/27 v1.10 Alias list (inputenx)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
multibib.sty    2008/12/10 v1.4 Multiple bibliographies for one document.
      Jn.aux
      Cp.aux
      Pt.aux
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
  mt-cmr.cfg    2009/11/09 v2.0 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
    MyCV.out
    MyCV.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  mt-mvs.cfg    2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
  omslmr.fd     2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

Comment: The [tag:biblatex] tag deosn't seem to apply.

Comment: If I replace `\end{dcoument}` by `\end{document}` I get your example to compile. Also, you probably want to remove personal information from your example.

Comment: @T.Verron That is an example information. Not my personal. and I did change it to {document} but its still not working

Comment: What is the exact error you get from running the posted example? Which file is not found? I ran it in texlive2012 and got no error and the address and phone number appeared at the foot of the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know what file is not found. Its just shows up an alert. As soon as I remove that \mobile and \address it works well.

Comment: What appears in the log (or is it just an editor problem?) what happens if you just run pdflatex on the command line?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am installing TEXLive and I will check if it works fine with it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is the error I am getting:
 (see the transcript file for additional information){C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.
9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}Trying to make PK font umvs at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The umvs source file could not be found.

Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font umvs could not be created.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file umvs): Font umvs at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the marvosym package which supplies the umvs font family. This should be installable under the miktex package system (about which I know nothing)

Comment: Either go to Settings and enable On-the-fly installation, or go to the Package Manager and install `marvosym` there.

Comment: @G-Man Don't forget to upvote David's answer if it helped you!

Comment: MiKTeX: Windows `Start` -- `Package Manager (Admin)` -- `m` then locate `marvosym`, mark it and add it with clicking on `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is certainly too late but I got it working by running :

```
initexmf --mkmaps

initexmf --update-fndb
```

Run this in windows command window (type cmd on run)